# ¿Como puedo enlazar webpay plus en asp net?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

estoy implementando sdk para transbank en asp.net mi código es el siguiente (se ejecuta tras clickear el botón pagar)

```
    {
        var transaction = new Webpay(Configuration.ForTestingWebpayPlusNormal()).NormalTransaction;
        var amount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalAPagar.Text);
        var buyorder = new Random().Next(10000, 99999999).ToString();
        var sessionId = Session["Empleado"].ToString();
        string urlReturn = "http://localhost:50086/Empleado/BandejaEntrada.aspx";
        string urlFinal = "http://localhost:50086/Empleado/Compra.aspx";
        string result = transaction.initTransaction(amount, buyorder, sessionId, urlReturn, urlFinal).ToString();

        Server.Transfer(result);
    }
```

y me arroja este error:

System.Web.HttpException
HResult=0x80004005
Mensaje = Error al ejecutar la solicitud secundaria para Transbank.Webpay.Wsdl.Normal.wsInitTransactionOutput.
Origen = LindaSonrisa
Seguimiento de la pila:
en LindaSonrisa.Empleado.Compra.btnComprar_click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Users\elnac\source\repos\LindaSonrisa\LindaSonrisa\Empleado\Compra.aspx.cs: línea 160

Excepción interna 1:
HttpException: No se encontró ningún controlador http para el tipo de solicitud 'POST'

mi HTML:

```
                <asp:Button ID="BotonCancelar" runat="server" Text="Cancelar" CssClass="btn btn-success float-right" onclick ="btnCancelar_Click"/>
               
                <button class="btn btn-success float-right" id="btnComprar" runat="server" onserverclick="btnComprar_click" >Comprar</button>
           
                <button class="btn btn-success float-right" id="btnAgregar" runat="server" onserverclick="btnAgregar_click">Agregar</button>
```

pd: dentro de la página ya tengo un formulario en la página maestra, por ende no puedo anidar un formulario dentro de otro